# javascript code dencryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

I know that this is not quite a question, however i've been looking at some websites and seem script as below:-

```
   var _0x34a8=["\x67\x6F\x6F","\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73","\x6E\x75\x6D\x62\x65\x72","\x67\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x3D","\x3B\x20","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x28\x3F\x3A\x5E\x7C\x3B\x20\x29","\x5C\x24\x31","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x3D\x28\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x2A\x29","\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x66\x6F\x72\x45\x61\x63\x68","","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74","\x5A\x73\x42\x5A\x6E\x56\x58\x6C\x63\x56\x57\x62\x49\x49\x70\x46","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72","\x74\x6F\x49\x53\x4F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F","\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x61\x6E\x61\x6C\x79\x74\x69\x63\x73\x2F","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x73\x72\x63","\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65","\x6F\x6E\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72"];
```

this was inside a  tag. Is there a way of decrypting this?

Comment: There are a few deobfuscators that will decrypt the string and sometimes even get readable code. Copy the strings into your Javascript console, and they will be turned into normal text (atleast in chrome).

Comment: Yes, looks like it's hex.

Comment: Decode hex, a regex like `(/\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/g` can help you

Comment: `["..."].join(" ")` gives

`"goo expires number getTime setTime toUTCString = ;  cookie (?:^|; ) \$1 replace =([^;]*) match length forEach  split 0123456789abcdef charAt charCodeAt ZsBZnVXlcVWbIIpF getDate substr toISOString http:// .com/analytics/ script createElement src setAttribute onload removeChild parentNode onerror"`

Comment: simply calling `console.log(_0x34a8)` after assigning this variable will do the job of "decoding" it

Comment: Correct, that will print the *array* of decoded strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few deobfuscators that will decrypt the string and sometimes even get readable code. Copy the strings into your Javascript console, and they will be turned into normal text (atleast in chrome).

Variable names will probably still be jumbled and unrecognisable, if you opt to try a deobfuscator.

You can start by copying the string array into your console, and having it decrypt them.

To turn that line into text, you can copy the array and join it with spaces:

```
["\x67\x6F\x6F","\x65\x78", ...].join(" ")

> "goo expires number getTime setTime toUTCString = ;  cookie (?:^|; ) \$1 replace =([^;]*) match length forEach  split 0123456789abcdef charAt charCodeAt ZsBZnVXlcVWbIIpF getDate substr toISOString http:// .com/analytics/ script createElement src setAttribute onload removeChild parentNode onerror"
```

These words get concatenated in different order to build JavaScript code; i.e:

```
var obf = ["document.write","you got haxed","(",")","\""]

eval(obf[0]+obf[2]+obf[4]+obf[1]+obf[4]+obf[3]);
```

Try using http://jsnice.org/ or http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/